ARK: Survival Ascended keeps crashing with LowLevelFatalError (error DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED with Reason: DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG)
I'm trying to play "ARK: Survival Ascended" and host a local LAN Server for myself and my friends. I have the strongest computer of all of us.
But the game keeps crashing every 30min or so and then everyone loses progress on the server that I am hosting.
I've tried to verify my Steam game files and I made sure all my drivers are up to date.
This is the error I keep getting when the game crashes:
Attach the debugger now, else press OK to continue.

LowLevelFatalError [File:C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Util.cpp] [Line: 873] 
hr failed 
 at C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Resources.cpp:312 
 with error DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED with Reason: DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_HUNG



Unhandled Exception: 0x00008000

CL: 564566 
0x00007ffe36d2ee5a KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ff64e85035e ArkAscended.exe!ReportGPUCrash() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsPlatformCrashContext.cpp:1822]
0x00007ff64e7f9e70 ArkAscended.exe!FOutputDevice::LogfImpl() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Misc\OutputDevice.cpp:70]
0x00007ff64ee6d396 ArkAscended.exe!D3D12RHI::VerifyD3D12Result() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Util.cpp:873]
0x00007ff64ee4b25a ArkAscended.exe!FD3D12Adapter::CreateCommittedResource() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Resources.cpp:316]
0x00007ff64ee08e4a ArkAscended.exe!FD3D12FastAllocatorPagePool::RequestFastAllocatorPage() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Allocation.cpp:2122]
0x00007ff64ee08b4e ArkAscended.exe!FD3D12FastAllocator::Allocate() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Allocation.cpp:2042]
0x00007ff64ee5cba8 ArkAscended.exe!FD3D12DynamicRHI::RHIAsyncCreateTexture2D() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\D3D12RHI\Private\D3D12Texture.cpp:1139]
0x00007ff650f36a5b ArkAscended.exe!FTexture2DStreamOut_AsyncCreate::AsyncCreate() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Streaming\Texture2DStreamOut_AsyncCreate.cpp:37]
0x00007ff650f440b6 ArkAscended.exe!TRenderAssetUpdate<FTexture2DUpdateContext>::TickInternal() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Engine\Private\Streaming\RenderAssetUpdate.inl:76]
0x00007ff650f40971 ArkAscended.exe!FAutoDeleteAsyncTask<FRenderAssetUpdate::FMipUpdateTask>::DoWork() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\AsyncWork.h:98]
0x00007ff64b5ce55e ArkAscended.exe!<lambda_2cfb882046ba83e24f4606b279dfb220>::operator()() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\Fundamental\Task.h:499]
0x00007ff64b5d2733 ArkAscended.exe!LowLevelTasks::TTaskDelegate<LowLevelTasks::FTask * __cdecl(bool),48>::TTaskDelegateImpl<<lambda_2cfb882046ba83e24f4606b279dfb220>,0>::CallAndMove() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\Fundamental\TaskDelegate.h:171]
0x00007ff64b5d68ee ArkAscended.exe!LowLevelTasks::FTask::ExecuteTask() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Async\Fundamental\Task.h:627]
0x00007ff64e6e8147 ArkAscended.exe!LowLevelTasks::FScheduler::TryExecuteTaskFrom<LowLevelTasks::TLocalQueueRegistry<1024>::TLocalQueue,&LowLevelTasks::TLocalQueueRegistry<1024>::TLocalQueue::DequeueGlobal,0>() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\Fundamental\Scheduler.cpp:349]
0x00007ff64e6da674 ArkAscended.exe!LowLevelTasks::FScheduler::WorkerMain() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Async\Fundamental\Scheduler.cpp:378]
0x00007ff64e6eacf0 ArkAscended.exe!UE::Core::Private::Function::TFunctionRefCaller<<lambda_abf63b4b71b3a09b60c8feab122cedbd>,void __cdecl(void)>::Call() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Public\Templates\Function.h:475]
0x00007ff64e720c94 ArkAscended.exe!FThreadImpl::Run() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\HAL\Thread.cpp:69]
0x00007ff64e86a596 ArkAscended.exe!FRunnableThreadWin::Run() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsRunnableThread.cpp:149]
0x00007ff64e86a3ec ArkAscended.exe!FRunnableThreadWin::GuardedRun() [C:\j\workspace\RelB\Engine\Source\Runtime\Core\Private\Windows\WindowsRunnableThread.cpp:79]
0x00007ffe37c11ed7 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
0x00007ffe3951a95c ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []



This usually is related to your graphics device crashing. I would try updating your driver first.
I found one Reddit post with a similar error. The Reddit post links to a YouTube video where you modify a registry entry. The instructions on Reddit are:


Click your start menu and type "regedit" and click on "Registry Editor"

Copy this text and paste it into the "address bar" at the top: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\GraphicsDrivers

Right click the white space in the right hand pane and select "New" -> "DWORD (32-bit) Value"

You will get a new item called "New Value #1" - Rename this to TdrDdiDelay and hit "enter"

Double click the new entry and make sure "Hexadecimal" is selected for "Base" and set the "Value data:" field to 3c

Repeat step 3 - 5, but this rename this entry to TdrDelay and use the same values. Only the name should be different.

Verify that your window looks like the one I have in the screenshot above

Reboot your machine and see if ASA runs any better.



Note: Messing with the Registry can be dangerous. You should generally be fine if you only modify the area specified in the steps, but beware that changing other registries could cause system instability.
Last, the Reddit user said they still had crashes, but for a different error, seemingly unrelated. Hopefully that's not the case for you.
If all else fails, you might need a new graphics card. I had a similar issue myself with two different games, and replacing the GPU was the only "fix" that worked.

I've used this fix before for some games, for the exact same error, and has helped a lot.

After lots of crashes and investigations with Hanli, we finally discovered that the cause of the crash was Microsoft Teams.
Every time we played, we were on a Microsoft Teams call with each other.
And as soon as we switched over to WhatsApp and stopped using Microsoft Teams, the crashes stopped happening too. Then we opened a Microsoft Teams call again and the game crashed again.
So I'm like 99% sure that the crashes are due to Microsoft Teams when we're doing a call in there.

So if anyone is getting this crash and updating drivers and Windows didn't work, then simply try closing some programs such as Microsoft Teams.

So I guess you guys know each other then? Good find - I too have had my share of software causing games to crash, notably GPU monitoring software.
